# UIToolbar grouped buttons (without space between)

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I can't find the solution, how to implement this:

[image]

I mean buttons Previous and Next.

Comment: you may put your comment as answer and I'll accept it as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a `UISegmentedControl`.  :)